# Update statement with custom variable using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to run an update statement using the following code:

```
DB::update('update users set elo = 44 where id = 10 limit 1', array(1));
```

This works fine, however I want to pass in a custom variable into the id instead of '10'. For example:

```
DB::update('update users set elo = 44 where id = $homeplayer limit 1', array(1));
```

However I don't think this is the correct way to do it as it is not working. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `array(1)` good for in the first statement?

Comment: Nothing! Turns out this is not needed, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the following two options should both work:

```
$id = 10; // make sure we have an id

DB::statement(DB::raw('update users set elo = 44 where id = ? limit 1', [$id]));

DB::statement(DB::raw('update users set elo = 44 where id = :id limit 1', ['id' => $id]));
```

although the following would be a bit more "eloquent"...

```
$id = 10; // make sure we have an id

User::where('id', $id)->update(['elo' => 44]);
```

---

**Edit:**
Please be aware that all of the above solutions will not fire any Eloquent events in case of an update. If you want such an event to be fired, you'll have to perform an update like so

```
$user = User::find($id);
$user->elo = 44;
$user->save();
```

Comment: By the way, it just came to my mind that there is actually an advantage of using `User::where(...)->update(...)` over `DB::table('users')->where(...)->update(...)`, as the latter will not automagically set the current timestamp on the `updated_at` column if `public $timestamps = true;` is set on the model. Reason is that the normal query builder has no knowledge about the extra timestamp functionality offered by Eloquent. (I also added a hint for Eloquents above, in case you use them.)

Answer (score 1):

```
DB::table('users')->where('id', 10)->update(['elo' => 44]);
DB::table('users')->where('id', 10)->limit(1)->update(['elo' => 44]);
DB::update('update `users` set `elo` = ? where `id` = ?', [44, 10]);
```

Comment: Consider adding some context so that the OP and future users understand how your solution solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following:

```
DB::table('users')->where('id', $homeplayer)->update(['elo' => 44]);
```

check out the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#updates) about query builder

Comment: Also a reasonable solution if you don't have a `User` model.